# Коллайдер работает неправильно

Tags: unity3d

Всем привет.
У меня есть скрипт который создаёт сферу по префабу. К данному префабу я прицепил `box collider`, и при входе в данную сферу скорость игры должна замедляться, но, первая сфера работает нормально, вторая не работает, третья нормально и дальше ничего не работает.

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Sphere : MonoBehaviour 
{      
    public float deceleration = 0.1f;     
    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider col) 
    {         
        if (col.gameObject.tag == "Player") 
        {             
            Debug.Log("Enter");             
            Time.timeScale = 0.1f;             
            Time.fixedDeltaTime = Time.timeScale * 0.02f;             
            GUI.Label(new Rect(0, 0, 120, 100), "Предметов собрано");         
        }       
    }

    void OnTriggerStay(Collider col)
    {         
        if (col.gameObject.tag == "Player") 
        {             
            Debug.Log("Stay");
        }      
    }

    void OnTriggerExit(Collider col) 
    {
        if (col.gameObject.tag == "Player") 
        {             
            Debug.Log("Exit");             
            Time.timeScale = 1;             
            Time.fixedDeltaTime = Time.timeScale * 1;
        }
    }
}
```

---

Подскажите пожалуйста почему, и если не сложно дайте совет как это можно сделать по другому?

Comment: Для начала покажите код как код, а не как картинка.

Comment: `using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Sphere : MonoBehaviour
{

    public float deceleration = 0.1f;
    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider col) {
        if (col.gameObject.tag == "Player") {
            Debug.Log("Enter");
            Time.timeScale = 0.1f;
            Time.fixedDeltaTime = Time.timeScale * 0.02f;
            GUI.Label(new Rect(0, 0, 120, 100), "Предметов собрано");
        }


    }
    void OnTriggerStay(Collider col) {
        if (col.gameObject.tag == "Player") {
            Debug.Log("Stay");`

Comment: `}

    }
    void OnTriggerExit(Collider col) {
        if (col.gameObject.tag == "Player") {
            Debug.Log("Exit");
            Time.timeScale = 1;
            Time.fixedDeltaTime = Time.timeScale * 1;
        }

    }
}
`

Comment: Ну почти то что надо.))

Comment: Я просто не понял как его скинуть полностью одним сообщением

Comment: Сейчас исправлю, секундочку)

Comment: А вы не знаете как это исправить?

Comment: А куда вы прикрепили этот скрипт и сколько?

Comment: Я его прикрепил на префаб сферы, только 1.

Comment: Сказать честно - не знаю. Вроде всё правильно. У меня больше вариантов нет, может другие помогут.